# Return focus after executing a function in IE5

Tags: javascript, html

I'll just answer the first question... Why IE5 you wonder, Because it's on a Windows CE device that I'm working with so I'm limited to use IE5. The application that I've made uses a webpage with a couple of elements.

I have 2 textfields or `<input type="text" />` and 1 `<textarea></textarea>`, I'm transferring the data from textfield 2 into the textarea. This works perfectly but I have one small issue. I want the focus returned on textfield 2 when the function is done so I can add more data to the textarea.

Can someone explain or show me a way how I can accomplish this?

https://jsfiddle.net/2quwap6L/2/

I've put my code in a fiddle because I think it will be easier.

Comment: Which version of IE5? Since I remember IE5.5 had alot more standards implemented than IE5.

Comment: ie version 5.5 i think